# Moment.js format giving wrong UTC Offset

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am in PST and my current UTC offset should be -07:00.

When I do this I correctly get the offset:

```
const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
const o = Math.abs(offset);
return (offset < 0 ? '+' : '-') + ('00' + Math.floor(o / 60)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + (o % 60)).slice(-2);
```

However when I use Moment.js like this:

```
const date = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
return moment(date).format('Z');
```

I get -08:00.

What's the deal?

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, what you're doing is setting the creating a moment object from the offset. If you inspect the date object created, you should see that it's `moment("1969-12-31T16:00:00.420")`.

What you should be doing is creating a moment object from the *date*, not the *offset*. Doing this will yield the correct result.

```
const date = new Date();
return moment(date).format('Z'); // "-07:00" for PDT
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but after various googling it is actually the same to do this: return moment().format('Z');

Comment: Yes, of course. I was correcting the error in your code and nothing more.